# R Equivalent of Stata Texdoc

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

In Stata, there is a beautiful package texdoc (https://repec.sowi.unibe.ch/stata/texdoc/help-file.html) that allows you to create customized latex tables explicitly within your script, without having to use some wrapper function,

```
texdoc init "table.tex", force replace
tex \begin{table}[H]
...
...
tex \end{table}
texdoc close
```

Would write the table.tex table into your folder. Does R have an equivalent? Ie; without having to use stargazer or xtable, ect?

Note that there is also an R package called texdoc, but this is totally different.

Comment: If you were writing all the LaTeX code yourself, you could just use `cat()` to print it to a file. I recognize `cat()` is also kind of a wrapper, but not one that generates the code itself.  `cat(..., file="table.tex", append=FALSE)` is the equivalent of the first and last lines above with `...` being the text you want to write to the file. .